# In .proto file can we use integer in message fields

Tags: python, proto

Need to create an integer field in message field in .proto type file, like below example.
message value {string 1 = 1; string 2 = 2;string 4 = 3;string 5 = 4;string 6 = 5;}.
Is it possible ?. Creating the .proto file for python